# css3 "new" style flexbox fails to stretch textarea in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, flexbox

I am having trouble getting the css3 flexible box layout model to work in chrome latest, example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        body { 
            background: #FFF;
        }

        div.content {
            position: fixed;
            width: 50%;
            height: 80%;
            top: 10%;
            left: 25%;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px 5px #333333;
            border-radius: 10px;

            display: -webkit-flex;
            -webkit-flex-flow: column;
            -webkit-align-items: stretch;
        } 

        div.content > * {
            -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: #FFFFFF;
            border: 2px solid gray;
            height:0;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <div>
          <label>label content</label>
      </div>

      <textarea>Text area test</textarea>

      <div></div>

      <input type="text" value="input field" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>​
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKzhk/7/) of this)

In the above example all elements correctly flex in the main axis, divs and span also stretch correctly in the cross axis, however input and text areas are not stretching correctly in the cross axis.  According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-flexbox-20120918/), they should.

I am not looking for a work around, rather wanting to know if there is something I am doing wrong or something I am missing in the spec that would prevent this from working.

Comment: For a textarea, "rows" and "cols" are both mandatory attributes. I wondered if the layout wasn't working because the HTML was (technically) invalid but adding them in doesn't seem to have worked (see: http://jsfiddle.net/nKzhk/20/).

Comment: It appears the latest Canary (25.0.1317.0 Mac) has the desired behavior. I suspect this is something that's been fixed since the stable release.

Comment: @ebidel - looks like your correct, and it's actually a browser implementation bug, I have confirmed with Canary on my machine (and with the release out today it's different again, but still wrong).  Add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @ebidel, this turned out to be a browser implementation bug, and is no longer a problem in recent releases.

Answer (score 0):

Textareas and input tags do not automatically inherit the max-width property for flexbox as they are not part of the box model. In order for them to act as a div you need to wrap them in a div and give them 100% width. This works in the current release of Chrome and Canary.

http://jsfiddle.net/nKzhk/29/

```
 textarea {
        width: 100%;
    }

<div class="content">
  <div>
      <label>label content</label>
  </div>

    <div><textarea>Text area test</textarea></div>

  <div></div>

    <div><input type="text" value="input field" /></div>
</div>
```